# CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation does not translate correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see two different behaviors for CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation between simulator mode and the real device.

(on iOS 8.1)
For an iPhone4, to get CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation to work on the real device, I have to translate by twice the amount.
On the iPhone4s simulator, I have to translate just by the amount with not scaling.

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but since both have the same number of logical pixels, I shouldn't have to adjust CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation to make translation work.

Here I have a view I'm pulling in and out of view by swiping:

```
CGRect menuOrigin = self.rootController.containerView.bounds;
switch (direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
    {
        NSLog(@"Initial Position: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.rootController.containerView.frame.origin));
        NSLog(@"Initial Scale: %f", [self contentScaleFactor]);
        NSLog(@"Initial Center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([self center]));
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-1.0 * widthToSlide, 0);
        self.rootController.containerView.transform = transform;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            self.rootController.containerView.transform = transform;
            [self.rootController.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"Final Position: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.rootController.containerView.frame.origin));
            NSLog(@"Final Scale: %f", [self contentScaleFactor]);
            NSLog(@"Final Center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([self center]));
        }];
    }
        break;
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
    {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0.0);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            self.rootController.containerView.transform = transform;
            [self.rootController.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
    }
    default:
        break;
}

[self.rootController.containerView setNeedsDisplay];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

NSLog goes like this for the iPhone4 real device:

```
2015-10-15 01:12:37.547 Local[5307:60b] swipeLocalPull adjusting width 183
2015-10-15 01:12:37.556 Local[5307:60b] Screen size: {320, 480}
2015-10-15 01:12:37.559 Local[5307:60b] Initial Position: {0, 66}
2015-10-15 01:12:37.974 Local[5307:60b] Final Position: {-91.5, 66}
```

and for the iPhone4s iOS 8.1 simulator:

```
2015-10-15 01:19:19.479 Local[56380:3061577] swipeLocalPull adjusting width 183
2015-10-15 01:19:19.480 Local[56380:3061577] Screen size: {320, 480}
2015-10-15 01:19:19.480 Local[56380:3061577] Initial Position: {0, 66}
2015-10-15 01:19:19.886 Local[56380:3061577] Final Position: {-183, 66}
```

The simulator is translated correctly. Notice, the real device translated only half way to -91.5. Why is this and how can I detect or compensate for this. Sorry if this question has been asked before but I could not find the root cause for this behavior. I only care about x translation at this moment.

Anyone have clues for this behavior.?

**Update**
By request, here's a few extra outputs:

---iPhone4 values---

```
2015-10-15 17:20:59.591 Local[5617:60b] swipeLocalPull adjusting width 183
2015-10-15 17:20:59.596 Local[5617:60b] Screen size: {320, 480}
2015-10-15 17:20:59.599 Local[5617:60b] Initial Position: {0, 66}
2015-10-15 17:20:59.601 Local[5617:60b] Initial Scale: 2.000000
2015-10-15 17:20:59.603 Local[5617:60b] Initial Center: {201, 99}
2015-10-15 17:21:00.015 Local[5617:60b] Final Position: {-91.5, 66}
2015-10-15 17:21:00.018 Local[5617:60b] Final Scale: 2.000000
2015-10-15 17:21:00.037 Local[5617:60b] Final Center: {201, 99}
```

---iPhone4s Simulator---

```
2015-10-15 17:39:59.850 Local[57069:3104390] swipeLocalPull adjusting width 183
2015-10-15 17:39:59.851 Local[57069:3104390] Screen size: {320, 480}
2015-10-15 17:39:59.851 Local[57069:3104390] Initial Position: {0, 66}
2015-10-15 17:39:59.851 Local[57069:3104390] Initial Scale: 2.000000
2015-10-15 17:39:59.851 Local[57069:3104390] Initial Center: {201, 99}
2015-10-15 17:39:59.852 Local[57069:3104390] Final Position: {-183, 66}
2015-10-15 17:39:59.852 Local[57069:3104390] Final Scale: 2.000000
2015-10-15 17:39:59.852 Local[57069:3104390] Final Center: {201, 99}
```

They both seem to be at @2x scale so I expect the same code to work for both.

**Working Code**

I got it to work with the following(if someone explains why, then I'll just mark that as the answer):

```
switch (direction) {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
        {
            NSLog(@"Initial Position: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.rootController.containerView.frame.origin));
            NSLog(@"Initial Scale: %f", [self contentScaleFactor]);
            NSLog(@"Initial Center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([self center]));

            CGPoint currentPos = self.rootController.containerView.center;
            currentPos.x -= widthToSlide;
            [UIView animateWithDuration: .4
                                  delay: 0
                                options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                             animations:^{
                                 self.rootController.containerView.center = currentPos;
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) { }
             ];
        }
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
        {
            CGPoint currentPos = self.rootController.containerView.center;
            currentPos.x += widthToSlide;

            [UIView animateWithDuration: .4
                                  delay: 0
                                options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                             animations:^{
                                 self.rootController.containerView.center = currentPos;
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) { }
             ];
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self.rootController.containerView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Can you try querying the scale of the view (well the screen) in question?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but UIView.h, above the frame property notes that you should not use frame when the view has been transformed.  Perhaps inspect the view's center instead, just to be sure?  Also, is it possible that your view's layoutSubviews (possibly triggered by layoutIfNeeded) is changing the view's frame?

Comment: These are good suggestions and I made an update. I've also tried removing layoutIfNeeded and it didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: I got it to work by using the center property exclusively. If someone explains why this works versus the original, I'll just mark that as the answer. Thanks for the help!!